# Add line on top of each Python file in current and sub directories

Tags: python, linux, perl, shell

I'm on an Ubuntu platform and have a directory containing many .py files and subdirectories (also containing .py files). I would like to add a line of text to the top of each .py file. What's the easiest way to do that using Perl, Python, or shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use Tie::File;
    for (@ARGV) {
        tie my @array, 'Tie::File', $_ or die $!; 
        unshift @array, "A new line";        
    }
```

To process all `.py` files in a directory recursively run this command in your shell:

`find . -name '*.py' | xargs perl script.pl`

Comment: I kind of prefer `perl -pi -e 'BEGIN { print "A new line" }' $(find . -name '*.py')` :)

Comment: @hobbs: I get the idea, but it doesn't seem to work for me (on 5.10)

Answer (score 6):

```
find . -name \*.py | xargs sed -i '1a Line of text here'
```

Edit: from tchrist's comment, handle filenames with spaces.

Assuming you have GNU find and xargs (as you specified the linux tag on the question)

```
find . -name \*.py -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '1a Line of text here'
```

Without GNU tools, you'd do something like:

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  { echo "new line"; cat "$filename"; } > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$filename"
done < <(find . -name \*.py -print)
```

Comment: You get the award for the shortest and most obvious way to approach this. You do have a potential bug with whitespace in directory or filenames, but that is easy to fix with `-print0` on the left and `-0` on the right.

Comment: @tchrist: Won't it merely print the answer to STDOUT instead of adding the line to the top of each file?

Comment: @David, no, the `-i` option for sed means update the file in-place. You won't see anything on stdout.

Answer (score 5):

```
for a in `find . -name '*.py'` ; do cp "$a" "$a.cp" ; echo "Added line" > "$a" ; cat "$a.cp" >> "$a" ; rm "$a.cp" ; done
```

Comment: At the end you probably wanted to `rm $a.cp`

Comment: @Didier: did you mean `find . -name *.py`?

Comment: @eugene y: Thanks for corrections. I also quoted the name for find.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.py')
            file_ptr = open(file, 'r')
            old_content = file_ptr.read()
            file_ptr = open(file, 'w')
            file_ptr.write(your_new_line)
            file_ptr.write(old_content)
```

As far as I know you can't insert in begining or end of file in python. Only re-write or append.

Answer (score 4):

This will

1. recursively walk all directories starting with the current working
   directory
2. modify only those files whose filename end with '.py'
3. preserve file permissions (unlike
   `open(filename,'w')`.)

[fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) also gives you the option of backing up your original files before modifying them.

---

```
import fileinput
import os
import sys

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for line in fileinput.input(
            (os.path.join(root,name) for name in files if name.endswith('.py')),
            inplace=True,
            # backup='.bak' # uncomment this if you want backups
            ):
        if fileinput.isfirstline():
            sys.stdout.write('Add line\n{l}'.format(l=line))
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

> What's the easiest way to do that using Perl, Python, or shell script?

I'd use Perl, but that's because I know Perl much better than I know Python. Heck, maybe I'd do this in Python just to learn it a bit better.

The ***easiest*** way is to use the language that you're familiar with and can work with. And, that's also probably the best way too.

If these are all Python scripts, I take it you know Python or have access to a bunch of people who know Python. So, you're probably better off doing the project in Python.

However, it's possible with *shell scripts* too, and if you know shell the best, be my guest. Here's a little, completely untested shell script right off the top of my head:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" | while read file
do
    sed 'i\
I want to insert this line
' $file > $file.temp
  mv $file.temp $file
done
```

Comment: +1 for using the right tool, `sed`, but you have a bug: You should be saying `-print0` to `find` and piping to `while IFS= read -d '\0' -r file`, to avoid issues with problematic file names.

Comment: Actually, spaces or tabs in names aren't much of an issue here (although LF in the middle of file names are). Looking over my program, the big problem is I didn't quote the variable `$file`. If there was a space in the file name, my program wouldn't work.